# PHP - Generate Functions from array of string

Tags: php

In my application i need many getter and setter and my idea was to generate them from an array, for example:

```
protected $methods = ['name', 'city'];
```

With this two parameters, i will need to generate the following methods:

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
  return $this->getName();
}

public function getName($lang = null) {
  return $this->getEntityValue('name', $lang);
}
```

And for city, the method will be:

```
public function getCityAttribute() {
  return $this->getCity();
}

public function getCity($lang = null) {
  return $this->getEntityValue('city', $lang);
}
```

Sure, i should need to generate the setter too (with the same logic).

As you can see, i will need a method with `get<variable_name>Attribute` and inside this call `get<variable_name>` and the other (getName) return even the same method (for each getter) and just change the `'name'` parameter.

Every method have the same logic and i would like to generate them "dynamically". I don't know if this is possible..

Comment: Give us an example on what you would expect to see when you run the functions

Comment: The two "getter" method you see is what i should need to generate. For the city variable, i should need to generate the two exact same method. I update with the city one

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the `*Attribute()` methods good for? I mean all they do is calling the second method.

Comment: I'm using Laravel and this is a "special" method. But the questions is about PHP, the name convention is just a Laravel feature :)

Comment: You can utilize [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

Comment: @Marty i was thinking to use `__get` or `__set`but mhh maybe with `__call()`is possible... you can provide me a short example ?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to do this. I'm not going to provide a full implementation but you basically want to do something like:

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    // Match the name from the format "get<name>Attribute" and extract <name>.
    // Assert that <name> is in the $methods array.
    // Use <name> to call a function like $this->{'get' . $name}().

    // 2nd Alternative:

    // Match the name from the format "get<name>" and extract <name>.
    // Assert that <name> is in the $methods array.
    // Use <name> to call a function like $this->getEntityValue($name, $args[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and let me know is it your requirement or not.

```
$methods = ['name', 'city'];
$func = 'get'.$methods[1].'Attribute';
echo $func($methods[1]);

function getNameAttribute($func_name){
    $another_func = 'get'.$func_name;
    echo 'Name: '.$another_func();
}

function getCityAttribute($func_name){
    $another_func = 'get'.$func_name;
    echo 'City: '.$another_func();
}

function getCity(){
    return 'Dhaka';
}

function getName(){
    return 'Frayne';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send this params(name, city or other) as parameter to universal method(if you don't know what params you can get)

```
public function getAttribute($value) {
  return $this->get($value);
}

public function get($value, $lang = null) {
  return $this->getEntityValue($value, $lang);
}
```

If you know yours parameters, you can use this:

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return $this->getName();
}
$value = 'Name'; //for example
$methodName = 'get' . $value . 'Attribute';
$this->$methodName; //call "getNameAttribute"
```